# Is Blocks is convinient way to use for multiple return values in objective c

Tags: objective-c, return-value, objective-c-blocks

In my iPhone - objective c project I have to return multiple values from a method

I thought of using Blocks to do so

like

```
  - (void)fetchValueForKey:(nonnull NSString*)key WithCompletionHandler:(void(^_Nonnull)( id _Nullable value, NSError* _Nullable error))completionHandler
    {
    }
```

I am asking this question because usually these kind of block params are used for async call backs, is this still ok to use blocks to get multiple return values? please shed some light, thanx in advance

Comment: Why are you not using Array

Comment: its not necessarily for async calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mask your intention!

If something is called a completion handler, everyone looking at the code (even the author of the code one week later) assumes some (asynchronous) callback.

In the given example, I think this could be suitable:

```
-(id)fetchValueForKey:(NSString*)key error:(NSError **)error { ... }
```

and would be inline with many frameworks we use (add the non-null decorators as you see fit).

In other cases, you might pack them in a dictionary with meaningful keys, i.e. `@{@"name" : ..., @"adress" : ...}`. This is much better then returning an array of different things which lacks semantic information completely.

If you want a type safe and very clean way, use a dedicated class with those properties. What often looks overkill is a pleasure to read later, and often it shows that the design can be improved considerably, and that class becomes a good citizen in your code base.